# Saving data with cakephp won't work

Tags: error-handling, save, cakephp-2.0

I'm trying to `load`, `edit` and `save` a record with `CakePHP 2.0` but I get a `generic error`  during the `save` method that don't help me to understand where is the problem.

if I try with `debug($this->User->invalidFields());` I get an `empty array`, but I get `false` from `$this->User->save()` condition.

Here is the controller action where I get the error:

```
public function activate ($code = false) {
    if (!empty ($code)) {

        // if I printr $user I get the right user
        $user = $this->User->find('first', array('activation_key' => $code));

        if (!empty($user)) {
            $this->User->set(array (
                'activation_key' => null,
                'active' => 1
            ));

            if ($this->User->save()) {
                $this->render('activation_successful');
            } else {
                // I get this error
                $this->set('status', 'Save error message');
                $this->set('user_data', $user);
                $this->render('activation_fail');
            }
            debug($this->User->invalidFields());

        } else {
            $this->set('status', 'Account not found for this key');
            $this->render('activation_fail');
        }
    } else {
        $this->set('status', 'Empty key');
        $this->render('activation_fail');
    }
}
```

When I try the action `test.com/users/activate/hashedkey` I get the `activation_fail` template page with `Save error message` message.

If I `printr` the `$user` var I get the right user from cake's `find` method.

Where I'm wrong?

Comment: Is it possible that it's failing to validate?

Comment: can you suggest me some alternative way to debug invalid fileds instead of `debug($this->User->invalidFields());`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the problem may be in the way you're querying for the User record. When you do this:

```
$user = $this->User->find('first', array('activation_key' => $code));
```

The variable `$user` is populated with the User record as an array. You check to ensure it's not empty, then proceed; *but* the problem is that `$this->User` hasn't been populated. I think if you tried `debug($this->User->id)` it would be empty. The [read() method](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#model-read) works the way you're thinking.

You could try using the ID from that `$user` array to set the Model ID first, like so:

```
if (!empty($user)) {
    $this->User->id = $user['User']['id']; // ensure the Model has the ID to use
    $this->User->set(array (
        'activation_key' => null,
        'active' => 1
    ));
    if ($this->User->save()) {
    ...
```

**Edit:** Well another possible approach is to use the `$user` array instead of modifying the current model. You said that you get back a valid user if you `debug($user)`, so if that's true you can do something like this:

```
if (!empty($user)) {
    $user['User']['activation_key'] = null;
    $user['User']['active'] = 1;
    if ($this->User->save($user)) {
    ...
```

This method works in the same way as receiving form data from `$this->request->data`, and is described on the [Saving Your Data](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html) part of the book.

I'm curious though if there's another part of your setup that's getting in the way. Can other parts of your app write to the database properly? You should also check to make sure you aren't having validation errors, like their example:

```
<?php
if ($this->Recipe->save($this->request->data)) {
    // handle the success.
}
debug($this->Recipe->validationErrors);
```

Comment: Thanks for the information, as you said the `$this->User->id` was empty, I've tried to fix it as you written but the problem sill the same, also with `$this->User->save($this->User->data)` without success. What can it be instead of the `$this->User` was empty?

Comment: Added a few ideas above, vitto

Comment: Thank you again. The second part of your answer resolved my problem, I needed to add data to `$user` and then save it. I also needed to change `$this->User->find('first', array('activation_key'=>$code))` to `...find('first', array('conditions' => array('User.activation_key' => $code)));`