# how do I know the reason of saving failure in CakePHP?

Tags: php, debugging, cakephp

I am new to cakePHP.t I thought this should be simple but I am having hard time to find the reason why saving in a controller action does fail.

I tried to print error

```
if ($this->MembershipRequest->save($this->data['MembershipRequest'])){ 
         $this->flash("All items are saved", array("controller"=>"home", "action"=>"index")); 
} else { 
        pr($this->MembershipRequest->validationErrors);
}
```

But it does not print anything. Could anybody give me right direction? 
I am looking for a good way of debugging cakephp app. One thing I just found out is Configure::write('debug',...) which gives great debugging messages. Is there any other tool? Thanks

Comment: check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8100803/saving-data-with-cakephp-wont-work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure of your format of `$this->data`, but I'm pretty sure you don't need to pass the "MembershipRequest' as a key in the save, try saving with `$this->MembershipRequest->save($this->data)` and it should work.

Also, check the `beforeSave()` methods you have in your MembershipRequest or AppModel, they should *always* return true, otherwise the save will silently fail.

For other debugging help, I suggest you look at the [CakePHP DebugKit](https://github.com/cakephp/debug_kit).

Comment: Agreed, just save($this->data) should do it.

Comment: Buddy. It does not matter. I verified that either way should work. I would rather want a good method to debug cakephp. But anyway, thanks

Comment: @Paul, no, [it must be in that format](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/view/1031/Saving-Your-Data).

Comment: @Dunhamzzz Well, the statement in my code is working too. It was the other thing caused the problem. I found it using configure::write. Thanks anyway.